# which iOS developer program should I purchase?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am developing an app for a local kindergarten on iPad. I am supposed to install this app to about 50 ipads that the kindergarten owns. (ad-hoc distribution only) I don't have an iOS dev program membership yet. I wonder which one should I get.

The individual & company program might have problem if I sell more than 100 copies, right?
There is little info about the enterprise program. And I don't really think my situation fit as an "Enterprise".

Thanks in advance.
Leo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the iOS program. Either the company or individual program will allow you to deploy to 100 devices ad-hoc, as well as sell or distribute in the store.

Enterprise is essentially if you need more than 100 devices annually for private distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for using Ad-Hoc. You can distribute the app to up to 100 devices, but AFAIK you can't delete any of those devices once they are set. You won't be "selling" the apps either, when you do it by Ad-Hoc, the apps are not distributed on the app store. You will have to do updates manually too.

Comment: I have also noticed the the mobile provisioning profile for ad hoc distribution will expire after a while and you will not be able to run those apps on the device until it is updated again with a new profile.